# getChildHtml inside of another .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, theme

I have a local.xml file that I have all of my "includes" in (if you want to call them that).

I have a nav.phtml file that is included inside of the header.phtml file with `getChildHtml('nav')`. In nav.phtml, I have a file that I want included with `getChildHtml('topSearch')`.

Is this possible? Is there a better implementation?

Comment: Gone through XML is magento standard. Don't use shortcut for magento.

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE. To better understand your question and what you are currently doing, it would help if you show your layout XML code. I guess you are looking for nested blocks which is totally possible but to give a useful answer with code, I would need to know what you already have.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by including this :)

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('template/templateName.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes Possible to use  getChildHtml('topSearch')  in header file.

Your local.xml code:

```
{{block type="module/blockfile" template="path to template"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow bellow steps

**Step : 1** add bellow code in your `local.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
       <reference name="top.search">
            <block type="core/template" name="top.search.nav" as="topSearchNav" template="page/html/nav.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**OR**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
       <reference name="top.search">
            <block type="{your-module-name/your-block-name}" name="top.search.nav" as="topSearchNav" template="{your-phtml-file-path}" />
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**Note:** Add your particular block type & template file in above code for eg. block type : `catalog/product_list` & template : `catalog/product/list.phtml`

Step : 2 Now add `getChildHtml('topSearchNav')` under the file `app\design\frontend\{your-package\{your-theme}\template\catalogsearch\form.mini.phtml`

Like :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearchNav'); ?>
```